# Javascript character replace all

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find all the characters ('?') of a URL and replace it with `&`.

For instance, i have `var test = "http://www.example.com/page1?hello?testing";`

I first attempted:

```
document.write(test.replace("&","?"))
```

This resulted in that only the first `?` would be replaced by `&` , then I found a question saying that I could add a g(for global)

```
document.write(test.replace("&"g,"?"))
```

Unfortunately, this did not have any effect either.

So how do I replace all characters of type `&`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

the thing you saw in SO is regex replace :

`document.write(test.replace(/\?/g,"&"))`   ( I thought you wanted to change & to ? , but you want the opposite.)

with the G flag - it will replace all the matches in the string

without it - it will replace only the first match.

Comment: This is correct but for clarification, always escape your characters if you're using any special chars.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when i try this it doesnt output the right result: http://jsfiddle.net/9mVr5/2/

Comment: @MarcRasmussen `hello.replace(/&/g,"?")` and not `test.replace(/&/g,"?")` http://jsfiddle.net/9mVr5/6/

Comment: @RoyiNamir same result http://jsfiddle.net/9mVr5/5/

Comment: @MarcRasmussen no. you got the wrong ver. jsfiddle.net/9mVr5/6

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the ? character like so:

```
test.replace(/\?/g,"&")
```

Comment: Also, you have your arguments in the wrong order.